# Excel vba apply filter 'filter by color' and 'Text filter' together in a single column

Tags: excel, vba

Column "A" has multiple values(as attached) and in which I need to apply filter  like 'Filter by color'(Red) and 'Text Filter', begins with "=CBC*" (both together). Meaning the output of the filter must not have the remaining values other than Cell Red Colored and Begins with 'CBC'.

[2 filters together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEk5w.jpg)

Comment: This cannot be achieved with the `AutoFilter` (standard table filter in Excel). So, you'll have to write your own VBA code to filter the data. Please note, that StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: You'll need to create a new 'helper' column that has a copy of column A in it (without the colouring). Start macro recording, put the filter on colour on column A, on text in your 'helper' column. Stop recording and examine the code.

Comment: @CLR AFAIK the column filters are add and cumulative. So, if I filter column A by color I won't see anymore the non-red rows and the filter on the new "helper column" won't matter. The only other option would be to filter on column A all red row **and** those rows without a color. Yet, I am unaware how to achieve that (filter by two colors).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean @Ralph. I saw the wording Cell Red Colored *and* Begins with 'CBC' - the 'and' had me thinking in boolean terms. Now I look again what Optimistic could be after is Red OR Textmatch. I'd probably build a UDF that returns the colour of a cell in that case and put that in my helper column.

Comment: @CLR I try to avoid UDFs whenever possible and therefore would rather go with a `Sub` directly instead of adding a volatile UDF and an unwanted helper column. But that's just me. Anyhow, let's first wait for the OP to be updated with the VBA code thus far written in this respect. That will help us understand what he wants and where the exact problem lies.